# encrypting id in Codeigniter that is not permitted url in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I'm using codeigniter2.1.4.my problem is when i use

> $this->encrypt->encode($row['service_id'])

in my view page ,it generates such a key that is not permitted url and i also want short encrypt key bcoz current encrypt key too big.Any solution?Thanks

Comment: please explain in details

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Imagine i'm using $this->encrypt->encode($row['service_id'],'1234') in view page.It generates myaccount/update/MwPwZv4cat9l9QLCcByGQgkCkinolrpXA2qbp2aDABBx9qHxEZvctaXUq8fYl5fXUDqwXgzhCmLJF4QrSqQOHA==  ,Then 'The URI you submitted has disallowed characters' error coming .If i chnage $config['permitted_uri_chars'] then it is coming properly.Any alternative solution? like using cart library

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to send the encrypted key as a POST parameter instead of GET parameter. In case you do not want to do that, look into

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars']
```

in application/config/config.php. Add the characters that you want to send in URL. Remember. THIS IS A SECURITY COMPROMISE.

You can always change to another cipher algorithm using

```
$this->encrypt->set_cipher();
```

This is known to mess up your sessions as sessions are encrypted using the default algorithm. So if you set session, change cipher and again try modify or set session, it wont work. You need to make sure you set back the cipher to default after your encryption is done.

Check and try to understand system/libraries/Session.php, especially around the line

```
$cookie_data = $this->CI->encrypt->encode($cookie_data);
```

If you are interested in finding answer to "WHY"

Comment: Tejas i think it will be better use POST for passing id without use encrypt function.Then how will be my url my current url is myaccount/update/1

Comment: Assuming you are using jQuery ajax,
`$.ajax({
url: 'myaccount/update',
type: 'POST',
data: { 'id' => 1},
success: function(data) {
}
});`

And in your controller - myaccount,
`public function update() {
$id = $this->input->post('id');
}`

This would get you the id you are sending in $id variable.